# How do I know the current source version on a local machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm woking with a team mate programming something in parallel with another group in the same solution.

But, my mate has a different version, the most recent, that is different from my own, older one. I would like to know if there's any way to know the exactly source version that I have on my machine, and then tell him to get the same change sets from the TFS Server.

Is this possible? There's any place that log this kind of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tf info` command will tell you the details of a file.  Included in this information will be the local version (the changeset that you have locally) and the server version (the latest version on the server.)

```
C:\Temp>tf info filename.txt
Local information:
  Local path : C:\Temp\filename.txt
  Server path: $/Project/filename.txt
  Changeset  : 1099
  Change     : none
  Type       : file
Server information:
  Server path  : $/Project/filename.txt
  Changeset    : 1099
  Deletion ID  : 0
  Lock         : none
  Lock owner   :
  Last modified: Thursday, May 26, 2011 10:04:49 PM
  Type         : file
  File type    : Windows-1252
  Size         : 619
```

Answer (score 2):

### To see what versions you each have:

In Team Explorer / Source Code Explorer, you may right-click on a file and  **View History** to see all change set history, and you may right-click  on a file and select **/advanced/Properties** to see what you have in your workspace.

The corresponding command-line comands are `tf history yourFileSpec` see [tf history on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and `tf properties yourFileSpec` see [tf properties on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzy14b58%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

### To get a specific version:

You may right-click on a file in Source Control Explorer and get specific version. This also has a corresponding command-line of `tf get [itemspec] [/version:versionspec]` see [tf get on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)